# Cannot access values set from Json in one class from another class! [JAVA]

Tags: java, json, database, class

Good evening Stackoverflowians! I'm working on a project to get sensordata in Json-format to a java application that parses the Json data with Gson (awesome) and then INSERT's it into a mySQL db.

Well the parsing and setting and getting all works fine and dandy, but when I want to access these values from the database class where I'm building the sql-statement all I get is null.. I really can't wrap my head around the issue so now I'm at your mercy, I will post the code samples below.

Thanks a bunch in advance!

```
    public static void printDB() {

    try (final Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://atlantis.informatik.umu.se:3306/svph1518_db_ht2016", "svph1518_2016264", "zumenyhyb")) {
        System.out.println("Database connected!");
        sensordata data = new sensordata();

        try (Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
          String sql = "INSERT INTO sensor_DB (TIME, ID, TEMPERATURE, HUMIDITY, LIGHT, PIR, VDD, RSSI, SNR, SF) VALUES ('"+ data.getTime() + "', '" + data.dd.getId() + "', '" + data.dd.getTemperature() + "', '" + data.dd.humidity + "', '" + data.dd.light + "', '" + data.dd.pir + "', '" + data.dd.vdd + "', '" + data.dd.RSSI + "', '" + data.dd.SNR + "', '" + data.dd.SF + "');";

          System.out.println(sql);
            // stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        }
        conn.close();

        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("");
```

This is the database connection class where i want to get the values from the Json-parsing.

```
public class urlConnector {

public void connector() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    URL url = new URL("SOME COOL URL I CAN'T SHARE WITH THE WORLD");
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    //make connection
    URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();

    urlc.setDoOutput(true);
    urlc.setAllowUserInteraction(false);

    InputStream is = urlc.getInputStream();

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(is);
    String response = reader.nextLine();

    System.out.println(response);

    sensordata[] sens = gson.fromJson(response, sensordata[].class);
    System.out.println(sens[0].getTime());
    System.out.println(sens[0].dd.getTemperature());
}
```

}

And this is the connection to the webservice that provides the Json, I don't know if you want to see the set/gets, but I guess not because they're exactly what you imagine them to be!

Comment: What you do mean "all you get is null"? A `NullPointerException` or no data? In your `printDB` you create a `new sensordata()` object. Where are the values in that Object set?

Comment: sensordata data = new sensordata();
You need to set the values of data otherwise they will all be null

Comment: Side bar:  building the SQL directly as a String is open to SQL Injection attack. Use a `PreparedStatement` to set the parameter values, especially if the device providing the sensor data is an IoT device.  Do you trust that cool URL?

Comment: What i mean by all i get is null is that the values in the sql statement return null as they are now, but im guessing that there's probably an issue with the sensordata object not carrying any values

Comment: And cheers andrew for the security notice, much appreciated!

Comment: SOLVED, I'm so stupid that I did not realize I was not returning anything from the urlConnector!